# Construct new column from last non-NA values for each row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `Depth` which consist of `LON` and `LAT` with corresponding depths temperature data. For each coordinate (`LON` and `LAT`) I would like to pull out last record of each depth corresponding to the coordinates into a new data frame,

```
> Depth<-read.csv('depthdata.csv')
> head(Depth)
      LAT      LON   X150 X175   X200 X225   X250   X275   X300 X325 X350 X375 X400 X425 X450
1 -78.375 -163.875 -1.167 -1.0     NA   NA     NA     NA     NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
2 -78.125 -168.875 -1.379 -1.3 -1.259 -1.6 -1.476 -1.374 -1.507   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
3 -78.125 -167.625 -1.700 -1.7 -1.700 -1.7     NA     NA     NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
4 -78.125 -167.375 -2.100 -2.2 -2.400 -2.3 -2.200     NA     NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
5 -78.125 -167.125 -1.600 -1.6 -1.600 -1.6     NA     NA     NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
6 -78.125 -166.875     NA   NA     NA   NA     NA     NA     NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

so that I will have this;

```
    LAT LON 
-78.375 -163.875    -1
-78.125 -168.875    -1.507
-78.125 -167.625    -1.7
-78.125 -167.375    -2.2
-78.125 -167.125    -1.6
-78.125 -166.875    NA
```

I tried the `tail()` function but I don't have the desirable result.

Comment: How did you get the third column in your output? What is the calculation?

Comment: No calculation, just to pull out each last depth data corresponding to each coordinates. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, you want the last non-`NA` value in each row, for all columns except the first two.

---

We can use `max.col()` along with `is.na()` with our relevant columns to get us the column number for the last non-`NA` value. 2 is added (shown by `+ 2L`) to compensate for the removal of the first two columns (shown by `[-(1:2)]`).

```
idx <- max.col(!is.na(Depth[-(1:2)]), ties.method = "last") + 2L
```

We can use `idx` in `cbind()` to create an index matrix for retrieving the values.

```
Depth[cbind(seq_len(nrow(Depth)), idx)]
# [1] -1.000 -1.507 -1.700 -2.200 -1.600     NA
```

Bind this together with the first two columns of the original data with `cbind()` and we're done.

```
cbind(Depth[1:2], LAST = Depth[cbind(seq_len(nrow(Depth)), idx)])
#       LAT      LON   LAST
# 1 -78.375 -163.875 -1.000
# 2 -78.125 -168.875 -1.507
# 3 -78.125 -167.625 -1.700
# 4 -78.125 -167.375 -2.200
# 5 -78.125 -167.125 -1.600
# 6 -78.125 -166.875     NA
```

**Data:**

```
Depth <- structure(list(LAT = c(-78.375, -78.125, -78.125, -78.125, -78.125, 
-78.125), LON = c(-163.875, -168.875, -167.625, -167.375, -167.125, 
-166.875), X150 = c(-1.167, -1.379, -1.7, -2.1, -1.6, NA), X175 = c(-1, 
-1.3, -1.7, -2.2, -1.6, NA), X200 = c(NA, -1.259, -1.7, -2.4, 
-1.6, NA), X225 = c(NA, -1.6, -1.7, -2.3, -1.6, NA), X250 = c(NA, 
-1.476, NA, -2.2, NA, NA), X275 = c(NA, -1.374, NA, NA, NA, NA
), X300 = c(NA, -1.507, NA, NA, NA, NA), X325 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), X350 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X375 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), X400 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X425 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X450 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("LAT", 
"LON", "X150", "X175", "X200", "X225", "X250", "X275", "X300", 
"X325", "X350", "X375", "X400", "X425", "X450"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```